# Underscore instead of a for loop

Tags: underscore.js, lodash

Given I have an array like this

```
var arr = [ { "language" : "en", "level" : "C2", "primary" : true }, 
            { "language" : "fr", "level" : "B1", "learning" : true }, 
            { "language" : "it", "level" : "A2" } ]
```

I want to collect all the "language" values into a single array, like this:

```
["en", "fr", "it"]
```

I know I can do it with a for loop, but how would I do it with Underscore / LoDash?

How would I order by one of the boolean fields, and then alpha ie: if ordering by the "learning" boolean:

```
["fr", "en", "it"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the combination of `_.sortByAll` and `_.pluck` functions (link to [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sitoliyesa/edit?html,js,console,output)):

```
var arr = [ { "language" : "en", "level" : "C2", "primary" : true }, 
            { "language" : "fr", "level" : "B1", "learning" : true }, 
            { "language" : "it", "level" : "A2" } ];

var res = _.pluck(_.sortByAll(arr, 'learning', 'language'), 'language');

console.log(res);
```

[.sortByAll](https://lodash.com/docs#sortByAll) will sort your array firt by `learning` field and then by `language`. And [.pluck](https://lodash.com/docs#pluck) will take the given field from every object in the array (`language` in your case).

Comment: Just a note that sortByAll is only available in lodash.